# Thanos' Second Gauntlet

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thanos

So at the end of Age of Ultron, during the post credit scene, we see Thanos grab a gauntlet (not sure from where) and says "Fine, I'll do it myself" or something like that, he puts on the gauntlet, end scene.

But we know that the gauntlet he is currently using was from Eitri's forge on Nidavellir.  Is that the same gauntlet?

I think that maybe it was the "fake" one that Hela knocks over.  Or could it be that the other gauntlet was lost, stolen, or fake?

Comment: Clearly NOT the Asgardian fake as that was for a **different hand**.

Answer (score 0):

From my own [**previous answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89230/where-was-thanos-before-the-events-of-avengers-infinity-war) on M&TV:

> Thanos decides to do it himself after (it is assumed) the events of *Age of Ulton* **although it's not clear when this event actually takes place** in the MCU timeline

> We do know that Thanos had the Infinity Gauntlet constructed by Eitri at Nedavellir but it seems that this took place **considerably after** *AoU* (and 
>    after *Thor: Ragnarok*)and we are just seeing the outcome as a *flash forward* and Thanos really started getting serious about the Infinity Stones just before *IW* after Odin has moved on from Asgard and Nedavellir was left undefended.*
>
> [**Updated: Per this answer on SF&F**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/194334/57069)
>
> > Per the film's *Directors/Screenwriters Commentary*, Thanos' motivation for deciding to gather the stones is that he finally (after many years of searching) learned the location of the lost Soul Stone. Before this he seems content to get on with obliterating one planet at a time and making sure that he knows *roughly* where the other stones are, safe in the knowledge that he's made himself powerful enough (through his armies and his 'children of Thanos') to go and collect them when the need arises.
> >
> > **Stephen McFeely:** *"The catalyst for the whole movie was when Thanos figured out where the Soul Stone was because he captured Nebula on his ship and rooted around in her brain and figured out that Gamora knew where the Soul Stone was."*
> >
> > **Joseph Russo:** *"It's the reason why he hasn't gone for it before, because he knows that the minute he does, the forces of the universe are gonna line up against him. If he doesn't know where the Soul Stone is, then what's the point?"*
>
> <sup>[**Source**](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/02/infinity-war-gauntlet-mcu-continuity-plot-hole-thanos/)</sup>

<sup>* and Asgard is, as we now know, destroyed in *Thor Ragnarok*</sup>

Essentially, it seems Nedavellir was destroyed **after** *Thor: Ragnarok*, and so Thanos could not have had the Gauntlet at the actual time setting of *Age of Ultron* so the post-credit scene in AoU MUST have been a **flash forward**.